# When to create .exe file using Java? Why it is needed?

Tags: java

I am looking for answers for the questions Can a java developer create an executable jar as in ".exe" file? Why it to be created and where it is used? Please brothers help me with these questions. Interviewer has asked me this questions because of these questions I got rejected. So please help me to know better about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: These "How, When and Why" questions have already been discussed a gazillion times all over the web - probably the reason they now made to the interviewers lists. Please do a minimum amount of research before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can transform a jar -> exe and it is mostly used to make a jar run easily on windows. If you double click a jar file it doesn't mean it has to be executed as well, but using an exe ensures this. Also you secure your jar a bit from decompiling.

But I really don't believe that such a question rejects you from a job offer ^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Luftbaum